# Browser-side path of an included file in PHP

Tags: php, path

In PHP,

- `$SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` gives absolute "path" portion of the URL that is called;
- `__FILE__` gives the absolute local path of the file that is being included

Thus:

```
/* /MyServer/stuff/include.php */
<?php echo $SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . PHP_EOL; echo __FILE__ . PHP_EOL; ?>

/* /MyServer/index.php */
<?php include("stuff/include.php");
      echo $SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . PHP_EOL; echo __FILE__ . PHP_EOL; ?>
```

When I go on http://www.example.com/index.php, I would get:

```
/index.php
/MyServer/stuff/include.php
/index.php
/MyServer/index.php
```

My question is: how do I obtain "/stuff/include.php", in other words, the "http" page to my included file? Of course I could hard-code it, or sort of deduce it programmatically, but I would like a sure fire way. Ideally this is some PHP magic constant I don't know about.

Comment: I'm a little confused. What exactly do you need to deduce at run time?

Comment: `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` may be what you're looking for, not sure but give that a try and see if it returns what you need.  If not maybe `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?  See also [$_SERVER variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Too see all of the information available to you, do a `print_r($_SERVER);` on one of your pages and check-out all the "magic" provided.

Answer (score 0):

The hard-code (config-file) variant is the best possible option.
There is no "magic constant" that would help you out.

When you look at the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php) there are options where you could possibly extract the script path. Note, however, that these values are server-configuration/request dependent and thus your "sure fire way" could backfire.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

$protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? 'https' : 'http';

$url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

echo $url;

$arrUrl = parse_url($protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
print_r($arrUrl);